# Installer Crashed - Removing Extra packages

Tags: system-installation

I am installing `Ubuntu 11.04` (i386) alongside my Windows 7, During Installation, I am getting an `installer crashed message` (when it tries to removing extra packages), but I was able to login to Desktop. How can I fix this problem?

Below the steps that I followed:

1. Downloaded Ubuntu desktop i386.iso
2. Burned to my USB stick
3. Rebooted system and started installation

My system info:

- Intel i3 processor
- 500 GB HDD
- Also one GB graphics card
- [syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/686960/)
- [Partman log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/686961/)

Comment: We need the logs. `/var/log/installer/syslog` and `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: How to add attachments to this..?

Comment: Use [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/686960/  - Syslog

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/686961/ - partman.log

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct log, but I assume /var/log/apt/term.log will contain more useful information.

Comment: Actually I came out of Ubuntu and now in windows 7.. How do I get that Log now..?

Comment: You can not. You need to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: How can i boot with ubuntu..? again with USB stick (with Try ubuntu option)..? will that get me the correct log..? or i have to install again and recreate that log..?

Comment: Wait, didn't you say that you could actually boot into Ubuntu (not the try option)?

Comment: Actually.. when i tried to install its said like its installer crashed... and it gone to the desktop... !! But after that when I tried to restart my system I couldn't see dual boot.. Just window 7..!!

Comment: Oh, ok. I would suggest trying to install again and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Actually i 've tried using Wubi Installer also.. same problem i got...

Comment: Could you please check the md5 checksum of the iso? http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/MD5SUMS

Comment: Yes i have checked...
8b1085bed498b82ef1485ef19074c281 *ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso
this one matches

Comment: This is very weird... Could you try installing again, but expand the console and see on what package it fails?

Comment: Again I tried to re install... But again same issue.. but this using Wubi.. And the log files..
syslog :  http://paste.ubuntu.com/687107/
/apt/term.log : http://paste.ubuntu.com/687108/

Comment: actually i took screenshot when the error came(expanded console) and  it stored somewhere but i am not seeing those two screenshots anywhere..?

Comment: Try opening the failed installation partition using the live cd and searching for them.

Comment: Checked but no luck not able to find any..!! But when i am taking scree shot .. It showed folder as Desktop.. But in desktop i couldn't find any.. Is there any other way to know what console message came at that time..?

Comment: Issue Solved ..!! Just unplugged ethernet cable and installed again..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved: As per a comment on the question, unplugging the ethernet cable solved the issue.